# Update jpanel contents

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` "presentation" with a `JComboBox`. This `JComboBox` takes elements from a database. I have another `JPanel` "insert" in which I insert database elements.

If I insert a new database element, I'd like "presentation" `JPanel` combobox updates with the newly inserted element. Is this possible?

Comment: are you following any software model like `MVC` or `Presentation` model??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use a model to populate your presentation JComboBox.  Populate the model from the database to start your process.

When you insert a new database element, you also insert that value into your presentation JComboBox model.  Updating the model will update the JComboBox.

Here's an example that would load a ComboBoxModel from a database.

```
ResultSet results = aJBDCStatement.executeQuery(
        "Select columnName FROM tableName");
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
while (result.next()) {
    model.addElement(results.getString(1));
}
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
```

Then later, you would just

```
model.addElement(elementString);
```

Comment: Could I have an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a **model** and `presentation model` would be a good start, have a look [here](http://databinding.tornado.no/)